# Discord.js v13 sending buffer as attachment results in invisible image

Tags: discord.js, buffer

I'm trying to send a buffer as an attachment in Discord.js v13.
I'm using the same code that worked in v11, with the necessary syntax changes to v13.

The image at the specified path does exist and if I save the buffer to my disk as an image, it works just fine.
If I send it as an attachment in Discord it results in an empty attachment like this:

[image: Empty attachment]

This is my code:

```js
const promise = fs.promises.readFile(path.join('./assets/Environment/Base.png')); //this image exists

Promise.resolve(promise).then(function(buffer){
    message.channel.send({content: `${message.author.username}'s base:\n⁣`, attachment: [buffer]}).catch(allerrors)
});
```

I asked in several Discord servers, but nobody was able to help me so I thought I'd ask here, does anyone know what could be causing this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send), you should send a buffer like this:

```js
message.channel.send({content: `${message.author.username}'s base:\n⁣`, files: [
    { attachment: buffer }
]}).catch(allerrors);
```

Tested on both discord.js v13 and discord.js v12.

Comment: That just results in this error: `TypeError [REQ_RESOURCE_TYPE]: The resource must be a string, Buffer or a valid file stream.`
I don't think it recognizes that syntax

Comment: Well, it's working for me. I think you have issue with the buffer. Somehow wrongly reading the file or something like that. The buffer might be empty, undefined, etc.

Comment: Try logging the `buffer.length` before sending the message.

Comment: You're right, it returns undefined, thank you! I'll see if I can figure out what the problem is ^^